# If global data is so bad, why doesn't that apply to databases (being technically just global data)

Tags: database, language-agnostic, global-variables

If global data is viewed as being so bad, with its potential for change anywhere in the system - then isn't the database due the same complaint?

The database being just a big persistent global data store right?

Comment: Why would a database be considered as bad as a global variable? The two are different as a brick and Jupiter and don't remotely fall into the same category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database is just global data if you have global database accessors, which is ***wrong***.

Technically a database is a data store to persist application data, that is, to preserve it between executions of the same code (as opposed to in-memory data). The data  in the database is not meant to be accessible to every part of the code, but just to specific parts.

Answer (score 1):

Global data isn't bad. [Global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Some of the things that make global variables bad also apply to databases.

Global variables introduce tight coupling, which makes applications fragile. Databases do the same - a change in the data can break the application unless you take steps to mitigate that risk. A lot of the work that ORM frameworks do is related to this - checking data types etc.

Global variables make it hard to understand code - you have to understand the code you're currently reading, as well as every other instance where that variable might be changed. This also applies to databases - again, ORM systems try to reduce this problem by re-phrasing the database data as application data.

Global variables can introduce concurrency issues. Databases mitigate this via transactions.

So, yes, there are drawbacks to using a database. But for most mainstream development projects, there aren't many alternatives...